# Django decorators passing variable to views

Tags: django, decorator

Hi Iam using Django Decorators.

I want to pass a variable from decorators to views function.

Is it possible means please help me..

```
def d(msg='my default message', alt="none"):
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn(request, **kwargs):
            if msg and alt:
               variable = "Read Only"
            return func(request, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator
```

I want the variable to be passed from decorators to view.

```
@d('hai', 'begin')
def company(request):
   print variable
   return ...
```

Anyone help me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't manipulate scopes that way.

```
def d(msg='my default message', alt="none"):
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn(request, **kwargs):
            if msg and alt:
               kwargs['variable'] = "Read Only"
            return func(request, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator

@d('hai', 'begin')
def company(request, variable):
   ...
```

Comment: Can u please tell me where will i get the value of variable in views by above kwargs['variable'] = "Read Only"?